# What is your life or What is your life like?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, difference, grammaticality

Which one is correct? Or are they both correct? What is the difference? Are they interchangeable?

I didn't find any results on google about the first one:

> What is your life ***like*** in two words?

or

> What is your life in two words?

Comment: "Describe/summarise your life in two words." The question is too vague. Is it about your life **now** or about your **whole** life?

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, I want to say this(now) and that(whole). So are they both correct?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand which question you are asking. They are two different questions. One has the possible answer "wonderfully happy" and the other "busy carer."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different questions.

> What is your life like in two words?

Here you are being asked to ***describe*** your life, its qualities, your subjective experience of it, etc. Given that you're being asked to do it in two words, the questioner is likely expecting some kind of snappy, creative, answer, almost like a headline.

> What is your life in two words?

Here you are being asked to ***define*** your life (in a very literal, clinical way). Given that a "life" is not really a tangible "thing", this question sounds a bit odd to me (I could imagine someone bemusedly answering, "In two words? My life is... my life?").

You might more commonly hear the first example expressed as:

> Describe your life in two words.

Interestingly (and perhaps quite confusingly), you may also hear:

> Define your life in two words.

This phrase, rather than the "What is" example, which I said was literal and clinical, would be understood to be requesting a more creative/descriptive/reflective/personal/abstract/autobiographical definition. "Definition" offers a bit more flexibility and creative opportunity than "description" (it allows and even encourages a high level of abstraction), and so the above may actually be the preferred option.